# Can we create seprate Apple ID for our each iOS device but share the same media library?

Tags: apple-id

My family and I (4 users) are using 4 iOS devices on a single Apple/iTunes account. We started with iPhone 4, and over the years we have added devices for my wife and 2 kids and as a result now we have a massive iTunes music library.

Now everyone wants their email, calendar, and contacts sync to iCloud and keep those separate, but they still want to use the same media library. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** Log in to the Apple ID that you want to use for iTunes and the App Store in the iTunes & App Store section of settings, then log in to the individual Apple ID for the iCloud account. These will be kept separate and allow individual iCloud accounts but a shared iTunes Apple ID.

Also, with the upcoming iOS 8, you can use [Family Sharing](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios8/family-sharing/).

Comment: The last I heard iOS app vendors have to turn on family sharing for their apps, don't know about music and movies.

Comment: Thanks George, this is really helpful. Now we have more reasons to wait for iOS 8.